# Jade: data-id with double """"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

in my `.jade`, I set a `data-id` with the `_id` a User model of mondodb, the problem is that the jade saves it with double `""""`. This is the jade

```
body(data-id = user._id)
```

And this is the output in html

```
data-id="567ab00e5a09b86915937f9b"
```

If i try with

```
body(id = user._id)
```

then the output is

```
id=""567ab00e5a09b86915937f9b""
```

I cannot understand the problem. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind using `#{variable}` syntax instead:

```
body(data-id="#{user._id}")
```

Comment: Works! this make no sense, why it's working with 'id' instead of 'data-id'?

Comment: Pretty sure it is because of the spaces. Jade is based on proper indentation and spacing is important.